# Is there a way to "Reverse" an NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Let's say that I have this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == NO", @"someAttribute"];
```

And I wish to reverse that predicate to :

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == YES", @"someAttribute"];
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a new predicate.

Comment: the pure logical 'reverse' formula would be `%K != NO`, anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't modify an existing `NSPredicate`.  But you can very easily create a new predicate that is the  “reverse” (or more precisely, the negation) of `filter`:

```
NSPredicate *notFilter = [NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate:filter];
```

See the [`+[NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate:]` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCompoundPredicate/notPredicateWithSubpredicate%3a).